# How do I write a delegate with params in F#?

Tags: f#, delegates, c#-to-f#

I have a C# delegate that I need to replicate in F#:

```
  public delegate object InvokeDelegate(string method, params object[] parameters)
```

How do I replicate this in F#?

I tried:

```
type InvokeDelegate = delegate of (string * (obj [])) -> obj
```

I'm not sure what's special about this, just that calling the delegate on some library functions doesn't work if I use the F# delegates that I've tried.

I thought it might be the `params` keyword, but I don't know how to do that in F#.

Comment: Try to remove one or both parentheses. Try `delegate of string -> obj[] -> obj` which may seem illogical but will perhaps work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a little messy since F# doesn't have `params` syntax sugar, but here's how you can do it:

```
open System

type InvokeDelegate = delegate of method: string * [<ParamArray>] parameters: obj [] -> obj
```

This will [compile down into the following C# equivalent delegate](https://sharplab.io/#v2:DYLgZgzgNAJiDUAfA9gBwKYDsAEBlAnhAC7oC2AsAFBVH4bYCSmAbsgNboAi6w6A5gEMS2ALzYYPfkPTZkYbKXREAFsjjZiAJwCWmPtgBU2ANoAeAAoDNA0gEFN1/AD4AutlRWbS9JoghZAEYAViZuALROgUFAA=):

```
[Serializable]
[CompilationMapping(SourceConstructFlags.ObjectType)]
public delegate object InvokeDelegate(string method, params object[] parameters);
```

See here for param arrays: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/parameters-and-arguments#parameter-arrays

And here for delegates: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/delegates

Note that your definition was also a tupled definition (the parentheses did that), compiling down into a delegate with a simple tuple as a parameter. This is probably one of the quirkier areas of F#.

Comment: I don't understand the logic behind using star (*), only without parentheses, instead of arrow, when it's tuple arguments. I stumble on this every time, and have to look it up. Is it just ... illogical?

Comment: I don't either, but given that it's (1) from pre-F# 1.0 days, and (2) F# language design strives for consistency, my guess is there was some kind of problem implementing it to allow for `->` and now we're stuck with that due to backwards compat. Maybe a docs update to clarify this is worth doing?

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with not conflicting with this legal syntax, used for returning functions : `type MyDelegate = delegate of int -> (string -> bool -> float)`